# P value of 0.000 using "comparegroups" R statistical package

Tags: r

I've been using the "comparegroup" R statistical package to conduct different types of basic analyses. Recently I came across a result of a multivariate analysis that showed a P value of 0.000. Small p values are usually presentent as "<0.001" by the package. Anyone knows what a p value of 0.000 represents in comparegroups package?

I have found this source (below) indicating potential meanings for p = 0.000 but none are in R or comparegroups package.

https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_should_p_value_be_reported_when_SPSS_report_it_0000

comparegroup package:

http://www.comparegroups.eu/

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/compareGroups/compareGroups.pdf

Thank you for your help!

Albit

Comment: Did you try extracting it to see what the actual value was?

Comment: Your question will get more attention on [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ok, thank you. How could I do the extraction?

Comment: Ok, will post in cross-valitated if can't find convincing evidence on the web.

Comment: Thank you alistaire and Dominic!